# Prove a functional obtains its extreme values on $\overline{A}$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Given $A \subset C[0,1]$ -- a set of functions that are twice differentiable on $[0,1]$ that satisfy:

$$f(0) = f'(0)=1$$

$$sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f''(x)|\leq 2$$

prove that:

$$\alpha: C[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

$$\alpha(f) := f(\frac{1}{2}) - \int_{0}^{1} f(x) \,dx $$

obtains its extreme values on $\overline{A}$.

I thought of using Arzela-Ascoli, but besides the following intuition on how to apply it in this case I'm at a bit of a loss. I thought that if I could somehow prove that $\overline{A}$ is compact (showing that $A$ is bounded and equicontinuous should suffice since this transfers to $\overline{A}$ which is also closed), then by Weierstrass (if I prove that $\alpha$ is continuous) I would get that $\alpha|_{\overline{A}}$ (not $\alpha$ as requested) obtains extreme values on $\overline{A}$.

Assuming I'm on the right track:

(a) How do I prove that $A$ is bounded and equicontinuous from the information provided?

(b) How do I formally claim $\alpha$ is continuous?

(c) How do I claim that the extreme values are in $\overline{A}$ for $\alpha$ (i.e. extending the claim I provided for $\alpha|_{\overline{A}}$)?

Comment: The main question, as it stands, doesn't make sense for me. $\alpha$ is linear, so $\alpha (\lambda f) = \lambda \alpha(f)$ and no extreme value can exist (given that $\alpha \neq 0$, which it certainly is).

Comment: Perhaps the meaning was indeed for it to be on $\overline{A}$? Would that make more sense?

Comment: What is the precise question then? I don't know what the intended question is. Even on the unit ball $\{f \in C([0, 1]) \, \vert \, \Vert f \Vert_{\infty} = 1 \}$ the functional doesn't attain it's norm $\sup_{\Vert f \Vert_{\infty} = 1} {\vert \alpha(f) \vert} = 2$ as maximum.

Comment: I double checked the question. I can't spot any errors on my part of writing it. I will sleep on it and re-read tomorrow. If nothing changes and no one has any further thoughts about this I will close the question. Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take any $f\in A$ then $$|f'(x)| =\left|f'(0)+\int_0^x f'' (x) dx \right|\leq 1+\int_0^1 |f''(x)| dx \leq 1+2 =3.$$
Now by Lagrange theorem $$\left|\frac{f(x) -f(y)}{x-y}\right|=|f'(\xi )|\leq 3$$
for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ therefore $$|f(x)-f(y) |\leq 3|x-y|$$
for any $x,y\in[0,1]$ and hence the family $A$ is equicontinous.

Moreover $$|f(x)| =\left|f(0)+\int_0^x f' (x) dx \right|\leq 1+\int_0^1 |f'(x)| dx \leq 1+3 =4.$$
so the family $A$ is a bounded set in $C[0,1]$ hence by Arzela -Ascoli criterion the set $\overline{A}$ is compact subset of $C[0,1].$

It is easy to observe that $\alpha $ is linear functional and $$|\alpha (f)|\leq 2||f||_{\infty}$$ thus $\alpha$ is continous function which of course attains its extremal values on compact set $\overline{A}.$

Comment: Superb! I'm just confused about the last bit - what exactly led to the conclusion that the extremal values are on $\overline{A}$ and not elsewhere in $C[0,1]$?

Comment: It follows from compactness of $\overline{A}$